# Why is a merged tag, which is made a synonym of another one, shown as being used in a question?

Tags: support, tags, moderator-tools

On May 6, I merged two tags on *Drupal Answers* (*uri* and *urls*) and made the second a synonym of the first, using the *merge* link I see in tag pages like [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blocks).

> [image: screenshot]

Since June 1, *urls* result as new tag, both in the page I see as moderator, and in the [page for new tags](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new).

> [image: Screenshot]

> [image: Screenshot]

Why does it happen? How can I fix this? Do I need to remove the synonym, and recreate it?

Comment: Possible a question which was deleted got undeleted. The merge process doesn't touch deleted content. Just run the merge again and it'll catch whatever question reappeared.

Comment: I didn't think of that. I thought a user selected the synonym tag when creating a question, and the synonym was _created_ in some way. It seems like an undeleted question could explain it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm it is as [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281174/why-is-a-merged-tag-which-is-made-a-synonym-of-another-one-shown-as-being-used#comment913398_281174) said: A question was undeleted after I merged the tags. After that, the tag appeared as new tag. I was not able to find which question used it because I made the tag a synonym.
Merging again the tags (without making them synonymous) made the tag disappear. I also got the confirmation page showing the tag was removed from a question.

It happened again with a different tag. Also in this case, merging confirmed the tag was going to be replaced in a question.

Answer (score 8):

The synonym pair appears on [this page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=merge), which means that the tags are synonymised but not merged. Hence the tag is not removed from any question that had it prior to synonymising. On the same page you should see a link that allows you to merge the tags.

Comment: I am sure I merged them, and made them synonyms. As moderator, in the page showing all the questions using a tag, I see a _merge_ link.

Comment: @kiamlaluno if you click that - then you'll get a preview of the number of changes that will occur (sometimes the overlap is a nice little sanity check to confirm one of them is indeed redundant) and an option to proceed with the merge or cancel...

Comment: I have already merged the tags. From the page showing questions using a tag, for example [tag:support], as moderator I see only the link to merge two tags, so it cannot be I simply made them synonyms, since there isn't a _make them synonyms_ link.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: That sounds like it shouldn’t happen. I can only tell you that, right now, these tags are only synonyms, but not merged. You should be able to merge them on the site I linked.

Comment: Well, you said I didn't merge the tags, which is not true.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Well, that’s the most likely case. Strictly speaking, all I can tell you is that they appear not to be merged right now. Whether this is due to a bug, somebody unmerging them, or you clicking the wrong button, I cannot tell. Please check whether it is possible to merge the tags on the page I linked. If yes, they are not merged; if not, they should not appear on that page. Either way, this narrows down the source of the problem.